# Splicing syntax parameterize disables Typed Racket type annotations

Tags: syntax, racket, typed-racket

When I run the following, I get a type error as expected:

```
#lang typed/racket
(require racket/stxparam)
(define-syntax-parameter x #f)
(syntax-parameterize ([x #'foo])
  (: n Number)
  (define n "string")
  'foo)
```

But when I use [`splicing-syntax-parameterize`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/splicing.html?q=splicing-syntax-parameterize#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsplicing..rkt%29._splicing-syntax-parameterize%29%29) instead, suddenly I get no type errors

```
#lang typed/racket
(require racket/stxparam
         racket/splicing)
(define-syntax-parameter x #f)
(splicing-syntax-parameterize ([x #'foo])
  (: n Number)
  (define n "string"))
```

Examining at the REPL shows that `n` has type `String`, despite the annotation.
The documentation for [`splicing-syntax-parameterize`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/splicing.html?q=splicing-syntax-parameterize#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsplicing..rkt%29._splicing-syntax-parameterize%29%29) claims that it treats definitions in the same manner as `begin`:

> Like syntax-parameterize, except that in a definition context, the body forms are spliced into the enclosing definition context (in the same way as for begin).

However, if I use `begin` instead of `splicing-syntax-parameterize`:

```
#lang typed/racket
(begin
  (: n Number)
  (define n "string"))
```

Then I *do* get a type error. Is there some reason `splicing-syntax-parameterize` strips away type annotations from definitions, but `begin` does not? I would hazard a guess it's because the `splicing-syntax-parameterize` is basing its behavior on the untyped `begin` form instead of the `begin` form from Typed Racket, and thus knows absolutely nothing about the `:` form. If that's the case, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. It turns out that `splicing-syntax-parameterize` has a somewhat strange expansion that doesn't play nicely with the way Typed Racket detects and installs type annotations.

I have written a fix for this bug, which [you can find here](https://github.com/racket/typed-racket/commit/425c584a3087942a7a8d5aaac34ab05bb1e330c3). As expected, your original program now fails to typecheck. This fix should be available in Racket 6.1.1.8 or greater, so if you need this behavior, use a snapshot build or use the newest version of Typed Racket.

Otherwise, this should be included in the next Racket release.